# How to define derived property with index?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am using mysql with hibernate 4.2.1 and my app is standalone. I.e. no spring, etc.

I have following classes:

```
@Entity(name = "families")
class Family {
   private String name;
}

@Entity(name = "persons")
class Person {
   private Family family;
   private String name;
}
```

My problem, is to have a derived property fullName for class person, 
constructed as concatenated family.name and this.name. Also, it will nice to have an index in DB for this property.

I tried something like this, but without success.

```
@Index(...)
@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
@Formula("family.name || ' ' || name")
private String fullName;
```

Namely, I do not understand what shall I write in @Index, and what is a content for @Formula.
Could you please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest to add new transient attribut in the class Person. In the get method, you can concatenate as you need (@Transient fullName;)

Answer (score 0):

@Formula is used id for:

If we want to apply a virtual property in your entity to get a calculated value, we can use @Formula annotation to set the formula. This formula can be as complex as we want.

```
@Column(name="length")
    private int length;

    @Column(name="width") 
    private int width;

    @Formula(" length * width ")
    public long area;
```

To calculate anything using your own formula

@Index is used for:

@Index applies the index at property level. If the property of an entity is annotated with @Index, an index with the given name will be applied on the column.

```
@Column(name="name")
    @Index(name="nameIndex")
    private String name;
```

Comment: thank you for example. Still not understand how do I refer to family.name; hibernate says here is a syntactic error.